# JSON Body in POST Using the Rust reqwest Crate

Tags: json, rust, http-post, reqwest

I'm trying to implement this `curl` call using the Rust crate [reqwest](https://docs.rs/reqwest/0.11.2/reqwest/):

```
curl -u [USERNAME]:[PASSWORD] -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d @content.json [WEBSITE]
```

The file `content.json` encodes a JSON object as the name suggests.

My code looks like this:

```
fn get_response() -> Result<String, Box<dyn Error>> {
    let content = std::fs::read_to_string("content.json").unwrap();
    let client = reqwest::blocking::Client::new();
    client
        .post([WEBSITE])
        .basic_auth([USERNAME], Some([PASSWORD]))
        .json(&content)
        .send()?
        .text()?
```

While the `curl` command works, I get a "malformed request payload" error message in the response when running the Rust code. Unfortunately, I don't have control over the website, so I can't debug it there.

My question is: Am I doing something obviously wrong? If there's no obvious problem, what are some options (e.g., additional headers) that I should try out?
(Of course, I already tried a few things but nothing worked)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [the documentation for `.json()`](https://docs.rs/reqwest/0.11.2/reqwest/struct.RequestBuilder.html#method.json) we can see that it expects a arbitrary serde serializable type. This indicates that what it's doing is *creating* JSON text from the given value. So, you're sending a JSON-quoted string containing JSON to the server, which is presumably not what it's expecting.

I haven't worked with `reqwest`, but it looks like for your use case with a JSON string, you would use `.body()` to provide the string and `.header()` to specify the JSON Content-Type.

Comment: Thanks! You are right! I just found the answer myself (I failed to reload the page in time to see your answer).
However, I did try to use `.body()` and set the content type header to `application/json` and it still did not work. So, providing a serde serializable type is the only solution that worked for me.

Comment: Note that `.json()` automatically inserts the `Content-Type: application/json` header

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out, the function `fn json<T: Serialize>(&mut self, json: &T) -> &mut RequestBuilder` does not work as intended when the `json` parameter is simply a string (slice) in JSON form.
When passing in a `struct` that contains exactly the same information as the JSON string, the code works.